# Download File from a Website, which is not accessible

Tags: cache, file-download

Im asking if the is a possibility to retrieve a file from a Website, which is not longer up.
I Thoght about Google Cache but it is not working.

I want to get this file [7+ taskbar numberer](http://rammichael.com/downloads/7plus-Taskbar-Numberer.zip)

Comment: Um... the website is most certainly is up! I just downloaded the zip file just by clicking your link.

Comment: well, yesterday it was down. And I thought this question would be infromative for general purposes.

Comment: Additionally, for those who come by here: `archive.org` might be a place to search for stuff as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because the website no longer exists doesn't mean the files don't. However, you'd have to know the URL and hope the web server itself is working.

If the file no longer exists on the server, you cannot get that file from that location.

If the file exists in other locations then of course it is possible but you'd have to try and fine the file (you could try searching Google by file name including the extension).

I would not expect Google Cache to cache files, only pages. So you can see the file because the HTML is captured (cached) but it doesn't meant he files will have been.

You may have some luck finding the file via torrent websites or contact the developers/manufacturers.

Please note though, that any file can claim to be any file - so virus check it first!

Comment: I googled the filename and found several other sites hosting the file.

Comment: Well, me too, but Any Link i found so far redirects to rammichael.com, or down.

Comment: I would highly appreciate if you can share a working link here.

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I retrieve a file from a website, which is not longer up?

> I want to get this file 7+ taskbar numberer

This link, http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-numberer, is working for me.

---

#### Speech recognition

> This utility has been designed for speech recognition users who use voice macros to switch between open applications and tray icons. It works on Windows 7 and Windows 8 operating systems, both 32-bit and 64-bit.

The download link on that page, http://rammichael.com/downloads/7plus-Taskbar-Numberer.zip, is also working.

---

#### What about the general case of downloading files from broken sites?

There is no general answer. Either there is a copy somewhere else or there isn't.

If there is a copy then you have to decide whether you trust the source of the copy.

Comment: yes, now it is up again. but what about the general case of downloading files from broken sites...

Comment: @Joel Answer updated